# Deploy angular 7, mongo, express, node application on own server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, deployment

I would like to deploy my angular application with nodejs, mongo, express js on my own server.

My way is:
-> `ng build --prod` (output is dist folder)
-> `ng serve` on dist folder

Start backend:
-> `node server` js file

But I think, it is not correct way od production stage. Added http server on express, there I create another index html view file with hbs, and there I use:

```
<body>
  <my-app>Loading ...</my-app>
  <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

But on dist server, there is multiple js files.

How can I create using ng option (no webpack or must be f.e. webpack?) my angular/mongo/node/express application (in 1, my own server, no aws, heroku, github etc). There is any correct way to do it?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Yes, but I think there is no any solution for that case. The most important question -> there is possibility to run it without webpack? If yes, there is any solution to run in from express js (node) http server? What is "production/official way" to do it? Everywhere I see heroku, aws, firebase etc. solution. On "developer, no prodcution" solution.

Comment: Good question. All tutorials saying about ng --serve and http-client package. Also need answer on this question from professional web developer.

Comment: If you google "MEAN", you will find a *lot* of articles on using these technologies together, such as this one: https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-1/ or jump to part 8 for the deployment: https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-8/

Comment: Thank You, but I think You dont know the answer or you did not read my question. According to the article, it is that same way, ng build --prod followed by node server. It is not correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to deploy an angular app using [Caddy Server](https://caddyserver.com/) as the webserver.

- Create a build of your Angular code by doing `ng build --prod-true`.
  This creates a set of bundled Js and Html files in the dist
  directory.
- Copy these files to where you want to run the app.
- Next go to the Caddy website and download the version of Caddy for
  your os. You can choose all kinds of features but for my deployment
  inside a firewall a plain build worked fine.
- Drop the caddy file in the directory that you put your compiled
  angular code.
- Create a caddyfile (just a file named caddyfile), add localhost:(your
  favorite port number).
- Run caddy and it will automatically serve your app by launching
  index.html.  You can view your app at localhost:port.

No messy node installation.  Caddy has all sorts of add-ons to deal with more complicated scenarios but the deployment is caddy.exe, caddyfile and your built code.